# WebSphere inspect queue messages

Tags: debugging, queue, jms, websphere, message

I'm developing an app for a WebSphere 8.5.5.0. I'm sending messages to queues. Everything works works so far.

Now I would like to inspect the sent messages.

I know there is a possibility within the WebSphere. But I can't figure it out.

I had done this already, but after changing my laptop I had to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using embedded JMS (SIB), then you can do it:

- via admin web console:

  `Service Integration > Busses > *busName* > Destinations > *queueName* > Queue points > *queuePointName*`

  Switch to `Runtime` tab, then click `Messages`
- Use the external tool [Service Integration Bus Destination Handler](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021439)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/) to manage the messages from the embedded WAS JMS Engine (SIB)